# Dual boot Ubuntu studio with Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, ubuntu-studio

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and I would like to install Ubuntu studio on a separate SSD. These systems will share EFI partition, SWAP partition, home (two different accounts for each installation), and a large partition called video. The root (/) would be on separate drives for each installation.
I tried to start installation on Ubuntu Studio, but the install did not recognize the other Ubuntu even though I mounted the existing EFI partition.
I also tried to create a separate /boot partition that I wanted to share between two systems - did not work.
Already tried this with Fedora but also did not work. The only distribution that was able to detect another OS was openSUSE. Unfortunately openSUSE had massive wayland related issues with my hard drive since fglrx driver was discontinued. Ubuntu has been rock solid so far.
Any suggestions?

Comment: *I would not share the* **home** *partition* between two different flavours of Ubuntu (and the same holds for different versions). Instead you can have your personal files in a separate **data** partition (and mount it via a custom line in each system's `/etc/fstab `file.

Comment: That's the same thing. I would not share the same account home directory with both systems. One would be "/home/account1" and another will be "/home/account2" only one will be mounted in each OS.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the installer to recognize another OS to do coinstallation. That is just a convenience feature. What you need now is to boot LiveUSB, run a tool called Gparted, and shrink the existing Ubuntu partition to free up some space, then create an empty partition there. Apply changes, run the installator, and install into the new partition.

Needless to say, one mistake with Gparted, and you lose all your data.

You should not try to share /`boot` partition between distros, it is a very bad idea for a new user. Actually, if you use EFI, you do not need separate /`boot` partition at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Barafu. I am not a new user. I have been using Linux since 1995. Redhat, Suse, Debian, Caldera, Slackware, Gentoo, Opensuse, Fedora.......I tried them all and more. I don't need to shrink anything as I was saying that this installation will go into a new SSD. I already tried what you're suggesting and my EFI partition got overwritten by Ubuntu. I do not have time for system reinstall at the moment. I will probably have to clone a disk and try again.

Comment: EFI partition overwritten? That some absolutely weird stuff, unless you checked the "format" checkbox next to it. You didn't, did you?

Comment: No, I was mounting it only. The only formatted partitions were new root and swap. I also experimented with legacy boot and sharing the same /boot partition for both OS.